# How do I get my rank column to refresh as I filter my other data columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello Stack Overflow community -- I am looking for a solution on how to filter my table on the REPORT tab (i.e. I want to avoid using the "Transform Data" function) and have my rank column on my report tab update as I make filter adjustments.

Right now, for example, when I filter out specific products from my product column, the corresponding rank column does not update along with it.

Visual example:

| **product** | **rank** |
| --- | --- |
| apples | 1 |
| oranges | 2 |

What I want to happen is if I filter out "apples" from my PRODUCT COLUMN, I want the RANK COLUMN to show "oranges" as rank #1. Now, when I filter out "apples", the rank column shifts all my data up, but oranges and the data that follows is stuck with its old rank

EDIT: I also want to know if I can filter my product column and have other columns dynamically update/refresh as well, such as Cumulative %, Market Share, and so on -- things that will require updates if the input data shifts.

Thank you!

Tried creating filters on the report tab, but columns like rank, cumulative %, market share, etc do not refresh with new rankings etc

Comment: Is Rank a measure or a column?  To recalculate based on the filter state it must be a measure.

Answer (score 0):

PowerQuery columns and DAX calculated columns are updated on data refresh only. If you want the report to react on slicers/filters, you need to use measures, like

```
Rank Measure = 
RANKX(
    ALLSELECTED( example ),
    CALCULATE( MIN( example[product] ) ),
    ,
    ASC,
    DENSE
)
```

[image]

This is also the reason why **all data analysis should be done in DAX, not PowerQuery**. So, you'll have to rebuild your *Cumulative %* or *Market Share* calculation as DAX measures, if you want to see the impact of filters and especially cross-filters, which is the very power of Power BI.

**Accept this answer, if it was helpful to solve your problem. If not, comment why!**